# In Dialog based app where should I put a main execution loop? In Dialog class or App class?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I am writing an app that communicates with, and controls an Arduino micro-controller across a serial (USB) link. The app is dialog based. I need a main loop that continuously sends commands to and receives input from the Arduino.

1. Should I put this main loop in the dialog class or in the app class?
2. If in the app class, then should the dialog be modeless?

A very simple example (without the Arduino and USB link stuff) would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not place this loop in any of the mentioned object. This most likely will render application unresponsive.

Create a worker thread in OnInitDialog and place the loop in the thread.

As for the sample, you should consult Arduino API documentation for the library you are using, or use VS plug-in.

Comment: Thank you. Since my post I did create a worker thread and started it in the dialog constructor. It is mostly working. Now I have moved the start into OnInitDialog and it seems to be working the same.